# Irregular slide effect with different elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have created (and w/the help of Stack), a small script to control some slide to view content. The issue is that some of the elements on the page jump/skip to the closed state. The code and content is identical for the elements, they just behave differently. I thought that is this was a css issue, but I have no clue now.

Have a look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benblustey/JeabZ/1/) and see if you can spot what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention. The Content2 is the slider that skips/jumps closed. Tested Chrome/FF/IE9

Comment: Both the elements titled 'Content' skip in IE8, but works perfectly in IE7. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure what the problem is exactly, because I don't have ie8 and it seems to work fine in FF and ie9. I did notice that you have '.slider h3' and '.deactive.h3', so try it with '.deactive h3' to see if that helps in IE8. Hope that helps in some way.

Edit: changed ie7 to 8